# How to copy resultset from MSSQL to MySQL? Maybe openquery?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to copy often the lasts rows of a single table in MSSQL to MySQL table.
I've created a java script and all works but I think that it's possible improve the performance.
I've replicate the table schema and import data with MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver connector adding it in MSSQL and using Openquery.
It's possible use it directly on java?
What is this the best way to handle this task?
Thanks in advance.
Luca

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) has a utility to do this.

In the program, connect to your MySQL Database, and then choose Database -> Migrate.

~Christian

Comment: Hi,MSSQL db receive between 1000-5000 new rows every two minutes all day. I want this task to be automatical via software and I've just write java code that handle it. Actually the software copy 1000 rows from local MSSQL to remote MySQL in 60 sec my goal is 5000 rows in 120 sec if it's possible...

Comment: Because the MSSQL db register gps location of a very large fleet. These gps tracker update their position every 2 minutes when a car it's running or all time that the car make a turn with a degree major then 35°. I need to copy all these selected data (that are only a little part of db) in a web server where it's possible follow the car on a map in real-time.

Comment: You could write a linux program that queries the MSSQL database, collects data, and then inserts it into the other database, then run that on a linux server.

Comment: Finally I resolve writing a Java program that made the sync, the other solution that I've tried are all too slow ;-)